# How to pass same output from one method to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

When I call Wrequest() method, it returns a XML response and within that response, I extract a id number (using getID() function).

When I execute the Wrequest() method, I get id  - "5219479" response, but when I execute the `getID()` method, I get a new id "5219480", whereas I would like the Wrequest() method to pass the same id to the getID() method.

```
   public static string WRequest()
    {
        string URL = "######";
        string method = "POST";
        string postData = newTemplates.createXMLIssue();
        string responseData = "";
        int statusCode;

        HttpWebRequest hwrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        hwrequest.Timeout = 60000;
        hwrequest.Method = method;
        hwrequest.KeepAlive = false;

        if (hwrequest.Method == "POST")
        {
            // code
        }

        // Attempt to receive the WebResponse to the WebRequest.
        using (HttpWebResponse hwresponse = (HttpWebResponse)hwrequest.GetResponse())
        {
            statusCode = (int)hwresponse.StatusCode;
            if (hwresponse != null)
            { // If we have valid WebResponse then read it.
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    // XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
                    // string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (statusCode == 201)
                    {
                        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                        var statusXml = xmlDoc.ToString();
                        responseData = statusXml.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                        //var statusElement = xmlDoc.Root.Element("status");
                        var statusXml = xmlDoc.ToString();
                        responseData = statusXml.ToString();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            hwresponse.Close();
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```

My questions is, how can I pass the same id response from the wREquest() method, into the getID() method?

```
            public string getID()
    {
        var document = XDocument.Parse(WRequest());
        var href = document.Descendants("link").Single().Attribute("title").Value;
        href = href.Replace("Issue", "");
        string id = Regex.Match(href, @"\d+").Value;
        return id.ToString();
    }
```

This is how I am executing the above methods in my pageload, for further reference:

```
        string nm = WRequest();
        string em = getID();

        Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(nm);
        Label2.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(em);
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Show the code for `output()` and also how you call `WRequest()` and `getID()`. There is no usage of `getID()` inside your provided code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Apology for the typo error, the `output()` method suppose to say `getID()` method.  I have updated my post, according to your request. Please advise further.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `WRequest()` inside your `getID()` method, which is calling the remote server, which I am assuming is responding with a new ID for each call that it processes.
That you will need to verify with which ever service you are calling.

To do what you want to do inside your question, you will need to change the `getID()` method to accept the XML string, that `WRequest()` is returning, as input and process that input to determine the ID returned.